# Compare values from one table with average calculation of value with same properties in other table

Tags: sql, select, db2, compare, inner-join

First post here... I'm trying to create select values from tableA in last 5 minutes and to compare those values each row by row with average(value) from another table.

For example:

tableA

```
 id | time_stmp         | name    | location | value
-----------------------------------------------------
1   2019-08-09-13.20     name1      loc1        450   
2   2019-08-09-13.20     name2      loc2        550
3   2019-08-09-13.20     name3      loc3        480
4   2019-08-09-13.19     name4      loc4        420
5   2019-08-09-13.19     name5      loc5        50
```

tableB is basicaly the same, only values and time_stmp are different

tableB

```
    id | time_stmp         | name    | location | value
-----------------------------------------------------
1  |2019-08-09-11.20   | name1   |  loc1    |   475   
2  |2019-08-09-11.00   | name2   |  loc2    |   525
3  |2019-08-09-10.40   | name3   |  loc3    |   435
4  |2019-08-09-10.20   | name4   |  loc4    |   256
5  |2019-08-09-10.00   | name5   |  loc5    |   420
```

Now, I want to create select statement where I'll compare fields (values) from tableA in last 3 minutes with average value of tableB where name and location are same.

I tried something like:

```
    select
  ta.name,
  ta.location,
  ta.value from tableA ta 
                where ta.value < (select avg(value) from tableB tb
         inner join tableB tb on tb.name=ta.name and tb.location=ta.location)
```

but didn't quite worked...

Output should be only values from tableA where value is less then average value of complete second table.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It would help if you showed the results you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select a.*
from table a 
where a.time_stamp > current_timestamp - 5 minute and
      a.value < (select avg(b.value)
                 from tableB b
                 where b.name = a.name and b.location = a.location
                );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `tableB(name, location, value)` and `tableA(time_stamp)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Query works but I'll need to work with time execution since it takes a lot of time to execute...